# How can I have ClickToFlash except for YouTube?

Tags: safari, adobe-flash, safari-extensions

I use the ClickToFlash Safari extension, out of concern for Flash security vulnerabilities and to remove annoyances. However, I do not like its replacements for YouTube video players over YouTube's own player.

How can I configure ClickToFlash so that it does not affect YouTube players (whether on YouTube pages or embedded), but blocks/replaces all other Flash? Putting “www.youtube.com/” in the “Allow Flash on these sites:” list works for YouTube itself, but not embedding.

Comment: Have you looked at the sites doing the embedding to check and see if Google is using a pattern of host names you can add in addition to www? Also, have you tried whitelisting *.youtube.com instead of restricting just the www host name?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

bmike's comment prodded me into actually, y'know, reading [the manual](http://hoyois.github.com/safariextensions/clicktoplugin/#control_lists), which led me to find that the whitelists are in fact substring matches. Therefore these settings work:

[image]

I had to find the `/v/` URL by looking at the source of a page with a YouTube embedding.

Comment: Well done - I'm now flash free so I couldn't test this out for you.

Answer (score 0):

These days, you need to remove `killers/YouTube.js` from "conversion scripts" in the General preferences pane. This seems to apply to both ClickToFlash and [ClickToPlugin](http://hoyois.github.io/safariextensions/clicktoplugin/). Note that after making the change, you have to restart Safari, then wait a second for plugins to load, then open a YouTube tab to test.

I believe Kevin's answer was correct in 2012, but [the FAQ now says](https://hoyois.github.io/safariextensions/clicktoplugin/help.xhtml#faq_youtubesafari8), "Starting from Safari 8, YouTube is completely Flash-free." I found whitelisting both youtube.com and googlevideo.com had no effect.